# Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter, implode

I have a query that's pulling a list of IDs. Those IDs are in an array and I need to search another table with those IDs. I tried using implode to make those IDs a string that I could use in a where clause but I keep getting this error.

My current code is:

```
 $query = $this->db->query('
        SELECT *
        FROM system_scoperights
        WHERE user = '. $this->session->userdata('username') .'
    ');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $scope = $row->site;
        $data[] = $scope;
    } 
    $dataScope[] = $data;

    $idList = implode(',', $dataScope);   <---- Error Line

    $where = 'WHERE scope_scopes.sc_ID IN '. $idList .'';
```

I've tried different things I found on forums like:

```
 $idList = implode(',', array_values($dataScope));
```

and

```
 $idList = implode(',', join($dataScope));
```

but none of those work. (I've never even heard of the join function)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I dont think there is a requirement for the '' at the end of the mysql query - just end the query string after the string concatenation! +1 for the style of the query string though, me likey ;)

Comment: I know you dont need the two ' ' at the end i just like putting them there cause it seems more organized to me.

Comment: The error says "Array to string conversion error"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$dataScope[] = $data;
```

but

```
$data[] = $scope;
```

therefore `$dataScope` has an array inside it's array. `implode` only work on one level, so that why you're getting this error.

You should note that this is actually possible in SQL:

```
 SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN (SELECT site FROM another_table WHERE ... )
```

which would eliminate the entire need for this code.

That is:

```
$where = 'WHERE scope_scopes.sc_ID IN (SELECT site
                                       FROM system_scoperights
                                       WHERE user = '. $this->session->userdata('username') . ')';
```

Comment: You'd need to specify a column in the subquery in order for that to work.

Answer (score 3):

I partially agree with Jay's answer...just remove the line:

```
$dataScope[] = $data
```

and use the `$data` variable directly since it's already an array:

```
$idList = implode(',', $data);
```

However you also should use ( and ) in your where clause:

```
$where = 'WHERE scope_scopes.sc_ID IN (' . $idList . ')';
```

Using sub-queries in your where clauses, although they do have their place at times, can cost a lot of overhead, especially using 'SELECT *'.  Never ask for more than you need from your db tables :)