# Returning an array to echo from sql query

Tags: php, sql, echo

The second echo, for user_name, prints correctly, but the first will only print array and give 'array to string error'.

My query should return an array of about 6 names.

Is there something I'm missing that is causing it not to be returning an array correctly or how can I tweak this so I can choose which $single_name to echo?

```
function get_all_names(){
    $this->db->select('username');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $Query = $this->db->get();
    $rows = $Query->result_array();
    return $rows;
}

 $all_names = array();
 $all_names = self::get_all_names();
 // $single_name = $all_names[1]; 
 // Above line did not work, I needed to add in ['username'] to it. 
 $single_name = $all_names[1]['username'];
 $user_name = ($_SESSION['username']);

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert( '{$single_name }'); </script>";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert( '{$user_name }'); </script>";
```

Comment: print the result using print_r($single_name) and check whether the result is an array or simple value?

Comment: i have made an edit to code. $all_signums is now $all_names

Comment: Does it work now? What do you get when you use var_dump($all_names);

Comment: Check this link it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510398/array-to-string-conversion-error

Comment: var_dump($all_names) gives me back....     array(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["username"]=> string(7) "nameone" } [1]=> array(1) { ["username"]=> string(6) "twotwo" } [2]=> array(1) { ["username"]=> string(7) "newname"}.... and so on....

Comment: FIXED, I needed to change the line - $single_name = $all_names[1]; TO $single_name = $all_names[1]['username'];      Thanks for your help guys

Comment: @KeithC , in case you've found an solution - please write it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$single_name = $all_names[1]
```

to

```
$single_name = $all_names[1]['username'];
```